# Unable to cast to string

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

I wrote some code as below but in scenario - 1 , it throws an error in 2nd line stating can not implicitely convert type string to bool where as in scenario-2 it throws error stating cann not implicitely convert type bool? to bool.

```
Scenario - 1 
    string Test = Employee.IsPermanent ? "Permanent" : "";
    Test = Test + Employee.IsClear ? "Clear" : "";  //Throws error
 scenario - 2

    Test = Test + (Employee.IsClear ? "Clear" : "") + (Employee.IsPermanent ? "Permanent" : "") + ( Employee.IsSalaried ? "Salaried" : ""); //Throws error
```

Note - IsPermanent  and IsClear are boolean variable where as IsSalaried is nullable boolean variable .

Comment: Bool and strings are different

Comment: But i am returning string only right (E.g Salaried)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you place this `Employee.IsClear ? "Clear" : ""` inside a parenthesis, it will work.

```
Test = Test + (Employee.IsClear ? "Clear" : "");
```

This is happening because the `+` will be evaluated first. So this result would be a string and from the left side of the conditional operator you would have a string instead of a bool or an expression that can be evaluate to a boolean value.

On the other hand, using a parenthesis the expression inside the parenthesis would be evaluated first and then the result would be concatenated with the `Test` .

This has to do with the precedence of the operators. A detailed explanation can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the issue without parentheses ?

Comment: Thanks buddy for your help .. I edited my question . can you please give answer for the second scenario too .. I will accept this as an answer

Comment: You welcome dude. I am glad that I helped. The issue in the second scenario is the fact that `Employee.IsSalaried` is a nullable boolean. You could try this `( Employee.IsSalaried.HasValue && Employee.IsSalaried ? "Salaried" : "")`

Answer (score 2):

The error shows that you try to convert a nullable boolean to a boolean, which you do in this statement:

```
(Employee.IsSalaried ? "Salaried" : "");
```

You should check if it has a value:

```
 ((Employee.IsSalaried.hasValue && Employee.IsSalaried.Value) ? "Salaried" : "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Test = Test + (Employee.IsClear ? "Clear" : "");
```

The precedence of operators can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx)